# What is the best way to keep track of 1000 RDS hosted databases?

Tags: amazon-rds, best-practices, monitoring, aws

I want to know what is 'best-practices' for managing an extreme number of RDS instances.  I have no problem managing five.  But managing dozens or hundreds, that's another task.  I'm thinking use a python or php script along with the AWS CLI to report back RDS statuses like maintenance due, or instance failure.  I know this is a broadly based question, but any feedback or direction on this subject would be appreciated.

Comment: Create an RDS database to keep track of them!